# Angular app - static List is emptied on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a login page with Angular. I have a Angular component (html, css and ts files) which handle this functionality. From the HTML, there are two fields and two buttons. Username, Password, Login and Register. If you enter an unfamiliar username and password and click on register, i want the TS component to add this user (With password) to the list of valid combinations.

If i login with my hardcoded user (michael), it works fine. If i register an user and login inmediatelly, it also works. But when i register an user and refresh the page, the newly registered User is gone from the list (users).

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="loggedin === false">
  <label for="username">Name</label>
  <input id=username [(ngModel)]="username" type="text">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id=password [(ngModel)]="password" type="password">
  <button type="submit" (click)="login(username,password)">Login</button>
  <div class="snackbar">
   <button (click)="register(username,password)">Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

export class User {
  username:string;
  password:string;

  constructor(username, password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  static users: Array<User> = [new User('Michael', 'admin')];
  username:string;
  password:string;
  loggedin:boolean;

  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedin = false;
  }

  login(username, password){
    let currentUser = new User(username, password);

    LoginComponent.users.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.username == currentUser.username){
        if (element.password == currentUser.password){
          this.loggedin = true;
        }
        else {
          alert('Incorrect password');
        }
      }
      else {
        alert('Unknown user');
      }
    });
  }

  logout(){
    this.loggedin = false;
    window.location.reload();
  }

  register(username, password) {
    LoginComponent.users.push(new User(username, password));
    this._snackBar.open(username +" is added", 'close', {
      duration :4000,
    });
  }
}
```

Main question: How can i keep the users array in memory when a refresh happens? Given i do not want to add a back-end (at this point of developing)

Comment: Store it in local/session storage?

Comment: Yup, local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Perfect, That sounds like it should work for now. @jonrsharpe can you post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window.localStorage to store the values..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API